# How to remove App Service Certificate resource

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

So I have SSL certificate bought directly using Azure portal.

Now I migrated from Azure and want to delete every resource from Azure except my SQL Server and database.

When I try to delete App Service Certificate I have this error:

> Operation name
>       Delete the App Service Certificate
>       Time stamp
>       Tue May 30 2017 11:47:36 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Standard Time)
>       Event initiated by
>       -
>       Description
>       Failed to delete the App Service Certificate. : Delete for 'JerrySwitalski' App Service Certificate failed because there are
>   still imported certificates derived from the App Service Certificate
>   in the source subscription. Imported certificates:
>   /subscriptions/77cf2897-8c03-413c-8e16-38ea0e025d72/resourceGroups/01/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/JerrySwitalski-01-SouthCentralUSwebspace,/subscriptions/77cf2897-8c03-413c-8e16-38ea0e025d72/resourceGroups/01/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/JerrySwitalski-01-WestEuropewebspace

As you can see below, I have only SQL Server and database and this certificate:
[image]

**How can I remove for good this certificate?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to azure resource portal (https://resources.azure.com )  and navigate to subscriptions --> `specific subscription` --> providers --> Microsoft.Web --> certificates and see if it is here and i think you can delete it from here directly.

Comment: It helped, thanks. It looks like that if certificate is not binded to any app service, you cannot delete it. But at least I could remove it manually with your solution.

Comment: This worked for me:
`resource explorer >> subscriptions >> >> resourceGroups >> >> providers >> Microsoft.Web >> Certificates >> (read/write mode) delete the certificate`.


The path given exists, but does not have delete functionality anymore.

Comment: As of Dec 2020, here's an alternative solution since the Delete button no longer works in Resource Explorer.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1096815-4df9-4b02-b94f-2d67ec84c87f/how-to-remove-app-service-certificate-resource

Answer (score 9):

Delete a certificate in Azure Resource Explorer

1. Access to: resources.azure.com
2. Expand "Subscriptions"
3. Expand "Resource groups"
4. Look and expand the resource group where the certificate is
5. Expand "Microsoft.web"
6. Click on "Certificates"
7. Choose the certificate you want to delete
8. Make sure you have selected on the top read/write and then hit on "Delete"

Comment: I was looking for similar solutions, but you pointed out how to drill down to the specific certificate and then, delete option was there. Thanks!